# openwrt prevent device from connecting to certain open wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I am working on a small project with my **Tp-Link MR3040** using barrier breaker.

I am using the command `iw wlan0 connect any` which will connect to any open WiFi network.

Where I currently live, Time Warner Cable has its open WiFi across town and I don't want my device connecting since it does not provide internet (sites I go to are forbidden 403) is there a way to "blacklist" that ssid?

Answer (score 0):

You can scan, and choose which one to connect to by yourself 
Get scan results with signal strength and mac using

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Parse it in a script and select which one to join manually. iw scan results would contain "RSN:" or "WPA:" or "WEP:" if they are not open. So you can wee out encrypted networks, and select one which is open, maybe with best signal strength "signal: -45.00 dBm".

Since its openwrt you can do it in a Lua script maybe.

```
buf = output from iw scan
buf = '\n'..buf..'\nBSS'     -- .. is concatenate in lua
```

Use this regex to match a single block (in Lua or anything else):

```
"[^A-Za-z%d]BSS"  -- %d is all digits in lua, maybe 0-9 otherwise
```

Within each block grep SSID, signal, and check if "[^A-Za-z%d]+RSN:", "[^A-Za-z%d]+WPA:", "[^A-Za-z%d]+WEP:" have any match, ignore the blocks which do, and ignore the ones with the SSID in your blacklist.